# Can I serve part of a static website from a different S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have followed the AWS documentation to setup a simple static website:

- S3 bucket `mydomain.com` -> contains the website files
- Cloudfront distribution -> configured to serve `mydomain.com` with https (redirect http to https)
- S3 bucket `www.mydomain.com` -> redirects to `mydomain.com`

Now, I have a second static site, which is independent of the main site. However I want to host it under `mydomain.com/myproject/`.

Currently I just copy the files for `myproject` into the same bucket in the folder `/myproject/`, but I was wondering if it would be feasible to have a separate bucket for `myproject` and redirect the URL to that bucket instead.

Could this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done by having two behaviors in your CloudFront distribution, one mapping /* to the origin s3://mydomain.com and /myproject/* to the origin s3://myproject.

Also, you can have both names as alternate CNAMEs for the distribution and use Route 53 ALIAS for them.

Comment: Thanks. Note: I needed to create a custom origin in the distribution which draws content from the ugly URL of the S3 bucket. Also in the bucket, the content still needs to be under a sub folder `/myproject`. Or at least this is how I got it working.